# Undefined reference to

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I'm doing an opengl/qt3 assignment, but I'm running into an undefined reference error:

```
Renderer.h:
...
#include "Mesh.h"
... Mesh mesh;

Renderer.cpp: 
...
mesh.load("ball.obj"); 
...

Mesh.h:
...
bool load(string filename);
...

Mesh.cpp:
#include "Mesh.h"
...
bool Mesh::load(string filename) { ... }
...
```

but the compiler complains about the line mesh.load("ball.obj") as an undefined reference... What is going on? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you compiling all the source files and linking them all?

Comment: You haven't linked the libraries.
Tell which IDE are you programming in and we'll tell you what you have to do.

Comment: Oh! I thought I checked everything... guess I forgot to add the files to qt designer... thanks! T___T

Comment: :) Go ahead and add that as your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add the files to QT Designer. Solved!

Comment: Now just click that green arrow to mark this as "the" answer.